# Get method from Jquery not hitting the .Net WebAPI

Tags: jquery, .net

I am new to WebAPI and i started with a simple project where i have put some login information in the model and here is my controller

```
public class UserAccountController : ApiController
    {
        UserAccounts[] userAccounts = new UserAccounts[]
        {
            new UserAccounts { Id = 1, FirstName = "Sam", LastName = "J", Email  = "Sam@gmail.com", Password="s" },
            new UserAccounts { Id = 2, FirstName = "Jack", LastName = "S", Email  = "Jack@gmail.com", Password="j" },
            new UserAccounts { Id = 3, FirstName = "Mark", LastName = "M", Email  = "Mark@gmail.com", Password="m" },
        };

        public IEnumerable<UserAccounts> GetAllUserAccounts()
        {
            return userAccounts;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetUserAccount(int id)
        {
            var userAccount = userAccounts.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (userAccount == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(userAccount);
        }
    }
}
```

I added an HTML page in the same project (webapi) and wrote a JQuery to retrieve the records, but i dont see any result or error. How do i debug or know whether it is hitting my service. What mistake i am doing?? Please help

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:56546/api/UserAccount",
            type: "Get",
            success: function (data) { 
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $(
                        Response.Write(data[i].FirstName)
                        )
                }

            },
            error: function (msg) { alert(msg); }
        });
    });    
    </script>
```

[image: Network tab in Developer window]

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the for loop in your success callback:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $(
        Response.Write(data[i].FirstName)
     )
}
```

There's no Response.Write defined in JavaScript, you'll want to use something like console.log:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i]);
}
```

For server-side, if you are using Visual Studio, you can also always run the debugger and set breakpoints on your API methods to see if they are getting hit.

Comment: Thanks Travis! I changed the code accordingly but still no response. When you sayit is Console.log i think i should be able to view that in Developer tools of Chrome. I set a break point also in VS but it is not getting hit

Comment: Yes, it should go into developer tools. You can also check the network tab to see what's happening with the request.

Comment: I think it is giving error in the beginning itself. In the network tab i see something like i have attached in the screen shot

Comment: Does it come up if you hit the URL (http://localhost:56546/api/UserAccount) directly?

Comment: Try adding dataType: 'json' to the ajax options.

Comment: I've implemented the same thing and it works just fine for me. Restart Chrome/VS and try again. The only other thing I can suggest is just use '/api/UserAccount' for the url.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are basing your simple project from the [Getting Started with ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) tutorial. However, your jquery is slightly different. What happens if you change your jquery to match their code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Send an AJAX request
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:56546/api/UserAccount")
      .done(function (data) {
        // On success, 'data' contains a list of user accounts.
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
          // Add a list item for the user.
          $('<li>', { text: item.FirstName }).appendTo($('body')); // changed this line to append to body since I don't know your markup
        });
      })
      .fail(function(data) {
        alert(data);
      });
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON("http://localhost:56546/api/UserAccount")
                .done(function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                        alert(item.FirstName) })
                    });
                });
        });

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't help. as Travis mentioned, if you can hit the url directly and you get results, then there is something else you aren't showing. add a `.fail` to the `.getjson` - i've edited to show you where.